# javascript: Trying to flatten array only one level

Tags: javascript, flatten

I am trying to write a function to flatten an array. I have part of the function working and I need help in the other half.

```
flatten: function(anyArray, singleLevel) {
  if (singleLevel == true) {
      flatArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], anyArray);
      return flatArray;
  }
  flatArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], anyArray);
  if (flatArray.length != anyArray.length) {
      flatArray = someObject.array.flatten(flatArray);
  }
  return flatArray;
}
```

if I type

```
.flatten([[[1],[1,2,3,[4,5],4],[2,3]]], true);
```

I want it to flatten only one level:

```
[[1],[1,2,3,[4,5],4],[2,3]]
```

Comment: I don't think the multi-level flat works as expected for arrays such as `[[[[[1]]]]]`

Answer (score 12):

Modern JavaScript allows us to handle this very easily using a variety of techniques

Using `Array.prototype.flat` -

```js
const arr =
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, [ 4, 5, [ 6 ] ] ], [ 7, [ 8, 9 ] ] ]
  
const flatArr =
  arr.flat(1) // 1 is default depth

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatArr))
// [[1],[2,3,[4,5,[6]]],[7,[8,9]]]
// [1,2,3,[4,5,[6]],7,[8,9]]
```

Using `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```js
const arr =
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, [ 4, 5, [ 6 ] ] ], [ 7, [ 8, 9 ] ] ]
  
const flatArr =
  arr.flatMap(x => x)

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatArr))
// [[1],[2,3,[4,5,[6]]],[7,[8,9]]]
// [1,2,3,[4,5,[6]],7,[8,9]]
```

Using a spread argument to `Array.prototype.concat`

```js
const arr =
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, [ 4, 5, [ 6 ] ] ], [ 7, [ 8, 9 ] ] ]
  
const flatArr =
  [].concat(...arr)
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatArr))
// [[1],[2,3,[4,5,[6]]],[7,[8,9]]]
// [1,2,3,[4,5,[6]],7,[8,9]]
```

---

Older version of JavaScript (ECMAScript 5 and below) can use techniques like `Function.prototype.apply` -

```js
var arr =
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, [ 4, 5, [ 6 ] ] ], [ 7, [ 8, 9 ] ] ]
  
var flatArr =
  Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr)
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatArr))
// [[1],[2,3,[4,5,[6]]],[7,[8,9]]]
// [1,2,3,[4,5,[6]],7,[8,9]]
```

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` -

```js
var arr =
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, [ 4, 5, [ 6 ] ] ], [ 7, [ 8, 9 ] ] ]

var flatArr =
  arr.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a), [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatArr))
// [[1],[2,3,[4,5,[6]]],[7,[8,9]]]
// [1,2,3,[4,5,[6]],7,[8,9]]
```

Using a primitive `for` loop -

```js
var arr =
  [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3, [ 4, 5, [ 6 ] ] ], [ 7, [ 8, 9 ] ] ]

var flatArr =
  []
  
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 1)
  flatArr = flatArr.concat(arr[i])

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatArr))
// [[1],[2,3,[4,5,[6]]],[7,[8,9]]]
// [1,2,3,[4,5,[6]],7,[8,9]]
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`concat` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) expects one or more arrays as arguments, whose elements will be appended:

```
[1].concat([2, 3], [4]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So if you are using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), that will flatten another level:

```
[].concat.apply([1], [[2], [3]]) // === [1].concat([2], [3])
```

So you can either use `push` instead of `concat`, or `call` (or just direct invocation) instead of `apply` to get only a single flattening level.

Answer (score -1):

if you use ES6/ES2015 you can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator. Something like this

```js
console.log(...[[[1],[1,2,3,[4,5],4],[2,3]]])
```