# Flattening arrays of coordinates to a single array

Tags: javascript

I've seen this unsuccessful SO question about [flattening arrays one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099123/javascript-trying-to-flatten-array-only-one-level).  Not sure if this query falls into the same hole.  I wonder if this is possible for an array of coordinates.  e.g.

```
var arraysections = [[
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100]
],
 [[680, 100],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
]];
```

to become..

```
var singlearray = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [680, 100],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];
```

I need `arraysections` for individual paths and `singlearray` for a full list of points.  Grateful for any tips.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your questions, but I have been using underscore a lot lately and find it very helpful for just such occasions: http://underscorejs.org/#flatten

Comment: tvm guys. Tick to @poke for first response and comprehensiveness, but you're both on the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s still the same. You can use `concat` to merge multiple arrays. You can do it the manual way by looping over the objects:

```
var singlearray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arraysections.length; i++) {
    singlearray = singlearray.concat(arraysections[i]);
}
```

Or do the fancy way using `apply`:

```
var singlearray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arraysections);
```

The latter works by basically calling `[].concat(arraysections[0], arraysections[1], ...)`. The first parameter of `apply` is the array object you are using as `this` (an empty array here is fine), and the second parameter is an array of arguments passed to `concat`. As concat can combine multiple arrays at once, and `arraysections` is already an array of arrays, we’re good to go here.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy, you just do the following:

```
var singlearray = [].concat.apply([], arraysections);
```

1. Concat accepts multiple arrays to concatenate.
2. Apply accepts array of arguments as the second argument.

This allows to pass all your the into concat without iterating over *arraysections*.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing @poke's answer. Optimize out the need for a for loop by using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), i.e.

```js
var arraysections = [[
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100]
],
 [[680, 100],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
]];
var singlearray = arraysections.reduce( function(p, c) {
    return p.concat(c);
} );
console.log(singlearray);
```

Alternatively, consider using [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to replace expensive [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) calls with a cheaper [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) call:

```js
var arraysections = [[
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100]
],
 [[680, 100],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
]];
var singlearray = [ ];
arraysections.forEach(function(e) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(singlearray, e);
} );
console.log(singlearray);
```